# Question on C[a, b]

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, metric-spaces

[image]

I am very unfamiliar with questions of this type, and am struggling to get my head around how to approach them.

For part (a), I tried finding a $\delta$ if the integrals were within $\epsilon$ of each other, but I'm not comfortable with how to proceed fully through the question as we've been given very little guidance on this.

For part (b), I was thinking of using letting $x_n(t)$ be a sequence in and showing it must converge in $A$, but again I'm just not sure of how to proceed.

Any help and guidance on both this question and similar questions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: (a) If $\|x-y\|<\delta$, then $\|x\|\leq \|x-y\|+\|y\|\leq \delta+\|y\|$. Then $|f(x)-f(y)|=\left|\int_{a}^{b}(x(t)^2-y(t)^2)\right|\leq\int_{a}^{b}|x(t)+y(t)||x(t)-y(t)|\leq \|x-y\|(b-a)(\delta+2\|y\|)$. So, as $\|x-y\|\to0$, for fixed $y$, you get that $|f(x)-f(y)|\to0$.

Comment: (b) $A=f^{-1}((-\infty,1])$. Since $(-\infty,1]$ is closed, and $f$ is continuous, then $f^{-1}((-\infty,1])$ is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(y)|&=\left|\int_a^b (x^2(t)-y^2(t))\,dt\right|\leq \int_a^b |x^2(t)-y^2(t)|\,dt
\\ \ \\
&\leq \int_a^b\|x^2-y^2\|\,dt=(b-a)\,\|x^2-y^2\|\\ \ \\
&\leq (b-a)\,\|x+y\|\,\|x-y\|
\end{align}
Now, if we assume that $\|x-y\|<\delta$, then $\|y\|\leq\|x\|+\delta$, so $\|x+y\|\leq2\|x\|+\delta$. Thus 
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\leq (b-a)\,(2\|x\|+\delta)\,\|x-y\|
$$
and so $f$ is continuous.

As for the set $A$, you have 
$$
A=f^{-1}((-\infty,1]),$$ and the preimage of a closed set by a continuous function is closed.